# Изменение положения текста. css+html

Tags: html, css

Как сделать так чтобы id="Corporation" была с лева, а id"Name" с права, но в одном ряде

```
html
<!--Подвал-->
<div class="footer">
  <i id="123">1</i>
  <i id="1233">1</i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.footer {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
 <i id="id1">(C) Corporation</i>
 <i id="id2">by Name</i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ответ предыдущего комментатора считаю правильным. Через FlexBox можно сделать. Но если не учил - то твой вариант float: right или float: left;
Вообще вариантов много, все зависит от твоей смекалки. Можно даже через таблицу запилить. Но это уже устаревшая технология.